# How to insert a Note to Practitioners section in IEEE transactions latex files

Tags: ieeetran, abstract

We use the famous class file called IEEETran.cls

Following is my attempt at creating an abstract followed by another section called Note to Practitioners which must have exactly the same style as the abstract section.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\title{Bare Demo of IEEEtran.cls for Journals}

\author{Michael~Shell,~\IEEEmembership{Member,~IEEE,}
        John~Doe,~\IEEEmembership{Fellow,~OSA,}
        and~Jane~Doe,~\IEEEmembership{Life~Fellow,~IEEE}% <-this % stops a space
\thanks{M. Shell is with the Department
of Electrical and Computer Engineering, Georgia Institute of Technology, Atlanta,
GA, 30332 USA e-mail: (see http://www.michaelshell.org/contact.html).}% <-this % stops a space
\thanks{J. Doe and J. Doe are with Anonymous University.}% <-this % stops a space
\thanks{Manuscript received April 19, 2005; revised January 11, 2007.}}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
\blindtext
\end{abstract}

Note to Practitioners:
\begin{abstract}
\blindtext
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

However, i want my result to look like this:

[image]

Did someone have the same difficulty? Any suggestion would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can redefine `\abstractname` to change the name of the word *Abstract*, for example:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
\blindtext
\end{abstract}

\def\abstractname{Note to Practitioners}
\begin{abstract}
\blindtext
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

[image]